# No XAML binding debugging with breakpoints in Visual Studio 2012 (RTM, on Windows 8 RTM)?

Tags: wpf, xaml, microsoft-metro, silverlight-5.0, visual-studio-2012

After upgrading my Silverlight 5 solution to Visual Studio 2012 (RTM), and then updating to Windows 8 (RTM), I noticed that when you set a breakpoint in XAML, you get the following tooltip in debug mode:

*The breakpoint will not currently be hit. Symbol not found: System.Xml.Xsl.Runtime.XmlQueryRuntime.OnCurrentNodeChanged2.*

I then tried to set a breakpoint in the XAML of a Windows Store App test project, and then of a WPF application, but I got the exact same tooltip.

I tried to repair Visual Studio 2012, but that did not change anything.

In Visual Studio 2010 such breakpoints worked fine.

Is anybody experiencing the same problem? Any idea on how to solve this?

Comment: I can t remember that you can set breakpoints in xaml (vs 12 i dont know but vs10)

Comment: @thefiloe: Actually you could since Silverlight version 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to enable symbol download and source from MS. As suggested here
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc667410.aspx

Comment: This worked! I did the following:
(1) In Tools/Options/Debugging/General: check Enable .NET Framework source stepping
(2) In Tools/Options/Debugging/Symbols: check Microsoft Symbol Servers and specify and directory to cache the symbols.
After all the symbols got downloaded, breakpoints in XAML (in Silverlight) worked. They did not, however, in either XPF or Metro (but maybe there is no such things in these environments).
Funnily, I can safely revert those settings in Tools/Options and clear the Symbols cache: everything still works --maybe this was all because of the migration to Win8...

Answer (score 1):

The solution for me was opening xaml pages with the Source Code Editor.

Right-Click xaml page->Open With...-> Source Code (Text) Editor

Answer (score 0):

Select the silverlight companion project of you application project.web, right click na go to properties, select the tab "WEB" then in the bottom in "Debuger" activate Silverlight check box.

Comment: Thanks, but this was already selected. Remember, I tool my Silverlight solution from Visual Studio 2010 and moved it to Visual Studio 2012. Breakpoints in XAML work perfectly well in Visual Studio 2010...